# Uniform convex space is reflexive proof

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm reading the proof that a uniformly convex space is reflexive from https://matthewhr.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/uniform-convexity-and-reflexivity.pdf (page 3)

I can follow all of the proof besides the second line, where it says 
'since $B_X$ is  norm-closed in $X^{∗∗}$, it suffices to show that $∀ε > 0 ∃x ∈ B_X$ such that $\|x^{∗∗} −x\| ≤ ε$.'

Could someone please care to explain this to me?
Thank you.